# Можно ли реализовать на сайте такую вещь, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на одной странице выходило всплывающее окно на другой странице?

Tags: веб-программирование

можно ли реализовать на сайте такую вещь, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на одной странице выходила какая то информация на другой странице того же домена? Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: Разве что через бэкенд, сокетами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без бекэнда это можно сделать через LocalStorage, WebSQL и даже через куки.

На одной странице записываешь значения, на второй или подписываться на событие или переодически перечитывать.

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не сталкивался с подобной задачей, но если это дочернее окно открытое через windows.open() - вполне возможно.[Информация по методу](https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods). В остальных случаях будет чуть сложнее, но думаю можно воспользоваться некоторыми хитростями. Если обе страницы находятся в пределах одного домена они имеют общий localstorage и другие ресурсы. На одной из страниц можно с определенной переодичностью опрашивать хранилище (наверное лучше в веб воркере), а на другой по клику на кнопку записывать туда значения.
И вариант 3, организовать коммуникацию через сервер и web socket. В этом случае можно такое провернуть даже на сайтах с разными доменами.

Других вариантов мне в голову пока не приходит.

Answer (score 1):

так как я сам ничего не понял по данным ответам, пришлось додуматься самому. На одной странице по нажатию кнопки создаете куки. На другой странице проверяете, если куки существует, то делаете появление всплывающего окна. Решение оказалось невероятно простым.

Comment: собственно Вам дали подобный ответ (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1029412/188366), и довольно таки не вежливо выбирать свой, такой же, в качестве верного. Люди старались, тратили время..

Comment: Прошу прощения, просто я не понял этот ответ и поэтому не смог его использовать

Comment: не надо извиняться, я вообще тут слева зашел, просто мне так показалось

Answer (score 0):

Для решение подобной задачи мы реализовали небольшой websocket сервер на базе STOMP  протокола и SockJS в качестве клиента. Данный сервис имел внутренний rest ендпоинт, который позволял в контексте нашего домена групп и конкретных пользователей отправлять сообщения. В момент конекта к данному серверу, клиент отправлял такой же jwt, что и использовал при общении с бизнесовым беком, таким образом websoket сервер имел возможность проверить права на создание подписок, отправляемых клиентом.