# Можно ли реализовать на сайте такую вещь, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на одной странице выходила определенная информация на другой странице?

Tags: веб-программирование

Можно ли реализовать на сайте такую вещь, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на одной странице выходила определенная информация на другой странице? Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли реализовать на сайте такую вещь, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на одной странице выходило всплывающее окно на другой странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1029394)

Comment: GET-запросы, например.

Comment: Или смотрите в сторону local storage. Но вопрос недостаточно конкретный.

Comment: если страницы загружены с одного домена - они могут обмениваться событиями (как с воркерами) ну и про localstorage Вам уже сказали

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте вопросы-дубликаты. Если вам что-то непонятно в данных вам ответах - стоит попробовать в комментариях к ответам попросить уточнить, а потом и самому задать более конкретный вопрос.